# h5 style does not show color effect

Tags: css, text-coloring

Below is small code snap. Though I have given color there it does not show. Underline and position is ok.

```
h5 {
  margin-left: 36%;
  color:#C0C0C0;
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Comment: [It works](http://jsfiddle.net/L3LLR/), we need to see more code

Comment: Provide us with more code or a JSFiddle and then we can help...

Comment: Problem was with style overriding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the web inspector tools in Chrome you will most likely see a more specific style that overrides your style.

For example:

```
body > h2 {
  color: green;
}

h2 {
  color: red;
}
```

A [JSBin to demonstrate](http://jsbin.com/asEzoye/1/)

[image: And a Chrome picture to demonstrate what to look for]

Is how Chrome Tools would show it.